# Show that $\sum\frac{1}{2k+k\sin{k}}$ is divergent using direct comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm not quite sure if I got how the direct comparison test works.

For a series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{2k+k\sin{k}}}$$
Is the following correct:

$$
\frac{1}{2k+k\sin{k}} \sim \frac{1}{3k} \le \frac{1}{2k+k\sin{k}} \implies \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2k+k\sin{k}}} \text{ is divergent. }
$$

Because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{3k}}$ is divergent, we know that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2k+k\sin{k}}}$ is divergent, too since the series's sequence is greater than $\frac{1}{3k}$.

Comment: Saying $a_k$ is divergent is not the same as saying $\sum a_k$ is divergent. Edited title.

Comment: Yes, thank you @ThomasAndrews

Comment: It is not true that $\frac1{2k+k\sin k}\sim \frac{1}{3k}.$ (Do you know what $\sim$ means?) But there is a relationship to $\frac1{3k}$ which is good enough to show divergence.

Comment: I thought it meant "approximately" @ThomasAndrews

Comment: As I understand the phrase, for "direct comparison" you don't make any substitutions based on (roughly) asymptotic equivalence.

Comment: No, it means "asymptotic."  What is the smallest that $\frac1{2k+k\sin k}$ could possibly be (in terms of $k$)?

Comment: If $\sin{k} \le 1$ for real numbers it should be $\frac{1}{2k+k}=\frac{1}{3k}$? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: $f(k)\sim g(k)$ means $$\frac{f(k)}{g(k)}\to 1.$$ That isn’t true here.

Comment: How does $\sin k\leq 1$ mean $\frac{1}{2k+k}=\frac{1}{3k}.?$ Hint: You actually need the lower bound for $\sin k$ too here, to ensure the terms are always positive.

Comment: Oh right so it's $\bigl[\frac{1}{k};\frac{1}{3k}\bigr]$! And all fractions within the interval are divergent. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Well, $\frac1k$ is not less than $\frac1{3k}.$ Inverting positive numbers changes the order. @j3141592653589793238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $\frac1{2k+k\sin k}\sim \frac{1}{3k}.$

But there is a relationship between $\frac1{2k+k\sin k}$ and $\frac1{3k}$ which is good enough to show divergence.